# class module - VBA - importing data from the excel sheet

Tags: vba, excel, class, csv

Hi I am new to VBA so please bear with me. 
I have created a class of employee which is supposed to use the data from the excel sheet. I did a quick search but I have not find how to import my data from the same excel sheet into my class modules. Here is my employee class module:

```
Dim C As Class1
Set C = New Class1

Type Employee
    Name As String
    Address As String
    Salary As Double
End Type
```

Now I have so many data for Name, Address and Salary in my excel sheet which I don't want to import them manually. Could someone please help me with that?

I know that there is a code in Ruby on Rails that can do so:

```
content = File.read("data.csv")
```

Is there such a thing in VBA?

Comment: You say you've created a Class, but your code shows a Type ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im assuming this is an excel macro. You can refer to the cell by using range objects. Look them up.

For example try making this method. you can use a for loop to do this over large ranges of data

```
public sub test()
     name = sheets("Sheet1").range("A1").value
     'test what that did with a msgbox 
     msgbox name
end sub
```